# PHP errors on Magento store after restoring backup

Tags: magento, ssh, backup

After failing to upgrade my Magento store from 1.4.1.1 to 1.7.02 I decided to go back to the backup I made before upgrading.

Unfortunately this gives a few errors when trying to access my website:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ziezap.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1125
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ziezap.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1125
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ziezap.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1125
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in /home/ziezap.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 151

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: you have been used an extension before so that new installation a) not finding a module b) or not finding overrided function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clear your cache - delete all of the files in /var/cache/, there's a chance that the config is cached.